# Using an extension method declared and implemented in interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, extension-methods

I try to understand the `Extension method concept in c#`, So I added this interface :

```
 public interface IExtension
{
   public static int Multiple(this int a)
   {
       return a * 2;
   }
}
```

In my **Main** method

```
 public static void Main()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Entrer un numero");
       int a =int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
       a.Multiple();
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

I get an error in `a.Multiple();` indicates that the method is not recognized.

Even I added a static class implementing the interface, I get this same error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In my knowledge `static` member in an `interface` doesn't make any sense, and you have the implementation??

Comment: You can't implement *any* method on an interface. Interfaces contain *no* implementation by definition. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @pana Interestingly, in Java 8 they added "default" methods to interfaces... So this is right in C# and .NET, but it isn't an absolute truth (considering how much similar C# and Java are)

Comment: I guess the OP is from Java background considering the fact that a method is being implemented within an *interface*. No harsh feelings lets fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/FidKGT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension methods must be in a `static class`, not in an `interface`

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static int Multiple(this int a)
    {
        return a * 2;
    }
}
```

And you should print the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.Multiple());
```

Note that your extension method can't change the value of `a` (because `int` is a value type), it can only return a new value!.

Check by adding

```
Console.WriteLine(a.Multiple());
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Just as a curiousity, in Java 8 Oracle added *default methods* to interfaces: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html They are a little like C# extension methods, but they are defined inside the interface. Types that implement the interface can override them, otherwise they "inherit" these default methods.

Comment: @LamloumiAfif You can't declare it: compilation error. https://ideone.com/13sL89 Or if you prefer the only beta Roslyn http://goo.gl/3Q14Vc

Answer (score 3):

This code should not compile. Please first read about extension methods in c# - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Extension method should be declared in public static class and interface is redundant.

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static int Multiple(this int a)
   {
       return a * 2;
   }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entrer un numero");
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int doubledNumber = a.Multiple();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is demo - https://dotnetfiddle.net/JPJD5g

Comment: Extensions must be declared in static classes. Static classes cant implement interface by definition. So you cant declare interface for this class.

Answer (score 2):

An extension method must be specified in a non-generic `static` class, as a `static` method. You cannot declare one in an interface.

Edit:

@LamloumiAfif must have a different and more magical compiler than I do.

[image: Compilation errors]

Comment: No, you can implement it in interface, you can test my code to see this

Comment: @LamloumiAfif I've tested your code, see my edit above.

Comment: So I made a mistake , I have no error before compilation , editor didn't indicate any error!!